# how to use jquery autocomplete?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

i am creating a web project using JSP, and is trying to implement a simple search for users from my database using jquery autocomplete, however i am having trouble understanding how it works. i have little to no knowledge on jquery and ajax just to let you know. i have done the following code and am stuck.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="ewa.dbConnect,ewa.sendEmail,ewa.pwGen,ewa.hashPw,java.sql.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.autocomplete.css" />
        <script src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="search" name="search"/>
        <script>
        $("#search").autocomplete("getdata.jsp");
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

getdata.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="ewa.dbConnect,java.sql.*" %>
<%! dbConnect db = new dbConnect(); %>
<%
String query = request.getParameter("q");
db.connect();
Statement stmt = db.getConnection().createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT username FROM created_accounts WHERE username LIKE "+query);
while(rs.next())
{
    out.println(rs.getString("username"));
}
db.disconnect
%>
```

if i am not wrong i read from a website, the parameter q is default and is just there, however how do i display the data? how do i pass the values from getdata.jsp into the autocomplete?

Comment: there should be 2 files, that may be helpful: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/06/tutorial-create-autocomplete-feature-with-java-jsp-jquery.html

Comment: hi that is the site i went it, but it did not provide enough documentation, and the code is two code somehow it did not get separated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're calling the autocomplete script tag before jQuery has been included. So, not having jQuery to latch onto (as the jQuery object hasn't been defined), nothing from the jQuery autocomplete plugin will load.

You have

```
 <script src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"
     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It should be

```
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
```

Reverse the order, and the Firebug errors you mentioned should disappear; I'm not sure it'll solve everything, but nothing will work until that's resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see jQuery UI being included (that one provides the autocomplete functionality)

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

So you need to include jquery.ui.autocomplete.js
(Or are you using the plugin autocomplete? if so, move to the jquery UI version)

Could also be that the data from getdata.jsp is malformed for the use in autocomplete.

How you tried debugging the javascript in a browser such as chrome or in firefox(with firebug)

Comment: nope, what is the jquery ui for? i thought i only need to include the jquery library from google, the autocomplete api and it's css

Comment: hi , just used firebug and errors i got are jQuery is not defined,$("#search").autocomplete is not a function

Comment: That means the jQuery library is not loaded when you execute .autocomplete. You should wrap you call in $(document).ready(function()
    { $("#search").autocomplete("getdata.jsp"); }

Comment: If you don't read the documentation about autocomplete or jquery in general then you will never will get it running. autocomplete you are using now is from a plugin, this is plugin is no longer neceserry because the autocomplete functionality is added to jquery UI (with other UI components)

Comment: hi, i read read the documentation and i do not understand why are there many files that are included when i download the UI. i can't find what are these files suppose to mean

Answer (score 0):

I usual give (for jquery UI autocomplete) a JSON formatted answer, while I see your answer loop give a CR delimited list.

In getdata.jsp instead of produce:

```
jim<cr>
jack>cr>
jhon<cr>
```

try to return:

```
[{label: 'jim', value: 'jim'}, {label:
 'jack', value: 'jack'}, {label:
 'jhon', value: 'jhon'}]
```