# populate combobox with XML data

Tags: xml, jsp

I have two combo box on my JSP, what i am looking for is like, I want to fill the combo box data through xml file stored on the server.

Scenario:-
Suppose there are two combo box, First combo box is having various country name and as soon as the user enters a character it should show all the matching words in the drop down and once a particullar country name is selected, the second combo box will have the list of states associated with that particullar country name.

Can anyone please guide me in orderto achieve the same.
Data of both the combo box are stored in an xml file.

Thanks,
Ars

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow Ars.

Firstly, extract your data to [JSON](http://www.json.org) format when sending to web pages. What you are referring to is usually done with JSON and Ajax requests. Have a look at things like JQUERY as helper library to make your life easy.

A simple solution would be to write a simple servlet that responds with a JSON string of country names. Then you do an Ajax request every time the user types another character and add the values to your drop down. This is not something specific to JSP.

Start with some tutorials on the matter:

[JSP autocomplete with JQuery](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/06/tutorial-create-autocomplete-feature-with-java-jsp-jquery.html) or [similar questions on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639670/how-to-use-jquery-autocomplete)

Comment: Thanks JacobusR, But the main thing is that, I have two combo boxes, and the data inside those combo boxes depends on the parsed XML.
If I select the country say India then it should automatically populate the second combo box with all the states of India.